# Não puxando informações do XML

Tags: c#, entity-framework

No momento onde importo as informações do XML, ele não separa e não joga para o `XML_List`, para da continuidade para o código, ele retorna nenhum valor nessa parte do código:

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
 List<Dados_XML> xml_list = xDoc.Descendants("ide").Select(ide =>
                new Dados_XML
                {
                    Nome_Cliente = ide.Element("nome_cliente").Value,
                    nNF = Convert.ToInt32(ide.Element("nNF").Value),
                    Serie = Convert.ToInt32(ide.Element("Serie").Value)
                }).ToList();
```

Esse seria o código inteiro.

```
 public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase xmlFile)
 {
    if(xmlFile.ContentType.Equals("application/xml") || xmlFile.ContentType.Equals("text/xml"))
    {
        try
        {

            var xmlPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + xmlFile.FileName);
            xmlFile.SaveAs(xmlPath);
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
            List<Dados_XML> xml_list = xDoc.Descendants("ide").Select(ide =>
             new Dados_XML
             {
                    Nome_Cliente = ide.Element("nome_cliente").Value,
                    nNF = Convert.ToInt32(ide.Element("nNF").Value),
                    Serie = Convert.ToInt32(ide.Element("Serie").Value)
             }).ToList();
            using (XML_Conn xmlCon = new XML_Conn())
            {
                foreach (var i in xml_list)
                {
                    var v = xmlCon.Dados_XML.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(i.nNF)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                       v.Id = i.Id;
                       v.nNF = i.nNF;
                       v.Serie = i.Serie;
                       v.Nome_Cliente = i.Nome_Cliente;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        xmlCon.Dados_XML.Add(i);
                        ViewBag.Result = xmlCon.Dados_XML.ToList();
                     }
                 }
              }
              return View("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Não pode ser importado o XML!";
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Não pode ser importado o XML!";
            return View("Index");
        }
}
```

XML:

```
 -<ide>

<cUF>35</cUF>

<cNF>98603820</cNF>

<natOp>DEV. PRODUTOS</natOp>

<mod>55</mod>

<serie>2</serie>

<nNF>54341</nNF>

<dhEmi>2019-08-02T17:44:35-03:00</dhEmi>

<dhSaiEnt>2019-08-02T17:44:59-03:00</dhSaiEnt>

<tpNF>0</tpNF>

<idDest>1</idDest>

<cMunFG>3542602</cMunFG>

<tpImp>2</tpImp>

<tpEmis>1</tpEmis>

<cDV>0</cDV>

<tpAmb>1</tpAmb>

<finNFe>4</finNFe>

<indFinal>0</indFinal>

<indPres>9</indPres>

<procEmi>0</procEmi>

<verProc>11.58.00.00</verProc>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9tS0.jpg

Comment: coloque o xml na sua pergunta!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic coloquei o XML.

Comment: E onde você tem uma lista? Não existe o nodo `nome_cliente`... Já debugou o seu código?

Comment: Inclusive o cabeçalho! é por causa dele que você está tendo problemas

Comment: Okay, então tirando o `nome_cliente` ou alterando o cabeçalho no caso uma parte do problema será resolvido, a outra parte é a lista, no caso coloquei um `List`

Comment: No momento que ele passa pela `List`, ele retorna valor 0